# Docker - non-privileged user can write to / inside container

Tags: permissions, docker

I've created a container, based off the centos:6.8 image using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:6.8
RUN adduser -m test
USER test
```

The image is then built using docker build:

```
docker build -t dockerdemo .
```

Then I start a container with:

```
docker run -ti dockerdemo bash
```

When I am inside the container, I appear to be able to write as the "test" user into the root directory of the container:

```
[test@9af9c4aeb990 /]$ ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root 4096 Oct 25 09:49 /
[test@9af9c4aeb990 /]$ id -a
uid=500(test) gid=500(test) groups=500(test)
[test@9af9c4aeb990 /]$ touch /test-file
[test@9af9c4aeb990 /]$ ls -l /test-file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 test test 0 Oct 25 09:49 /test-file
```

I am expecting to see `Permission denied` when I run the `touch` command.

If I alter the `Dockerfile` and remove the `USER` statement, and rebuild, then I can `su` to the "test" user inside the container and I get the behaviour I would expect:

```
[root@d16277f693d8 /]# su - test
[test@d16277f693d8 ~]$ id      
uid=500(test) gid=500(test) groups=500(test)
[test@d16277f693d8 ~]$ ls -ld /    
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root 4096 Oct 25 09:50 /
[test@d16277f693d8 ~]$ touch /test-file
touch: cannot touch `/test-file': Permission denied
```

Have I misunderstood how user permissions work inside containers?

Is there a way to produce my expected behaviour?

Comment: If you go 'inside the container' through the side/back door, instead of the normal process (cmd/entrypoint) -- you are not test.   Do a whoami to verify.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean when you say "through the side/back door". I started each with "docker run -ti image-name bash".

Comment: I mean, if you just did docker run image-name, it works as advertised.   From the docs:

The USER instruction sets the user name or UID to use when running the image and for any RUN, CMD and ENTRYPOINT instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile.     You are running the container with none of the above.

Comment: I was using docker run to start the container. I've updated the original description so that it is explicit about the commands I've used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a vulnerability announced in 1.12.2 that your scenario matches. [Release 1.12.3](https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.12.3) just came out yesterday to fix this issue and CVE-2016-8867 was registered on the vulnerability. It's an internal container privilege escalation, so limited impact, but still worth the upgrade.

Comment: I can confirm that upgrading to 1.12.3 fixed my problem! Thanks very much.